# ASP.NET MVC - MapRoute versus routes.Add (and 404s)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm just getting started with ASP.NET MVC.

What is the difference between MapRoute and routes.Add ?
Should I just be using MapRoute? Can I map multiple routes? Which "maps" take precedence... those you called first or last?

I'd like to be able to do something similiar to the StackOverflow does for users.
But I would like the URL to fit this pattern:
"User/{domain}/{username}" to be routed to a UserController

and for all other requests to do the typical ASP.NET MVC routing. ex:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );
```

**UPDATE:**
When using the URL: http://localhost:3962/User/MYDOMAIN/BTYNDALL
I get the error: *HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "User",                                                     
            "User/{domain}/{username}",                           
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index" }      
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your update to this question is really a different question... you sure you want to mingle them?

Comment: Can you paste the code from the Index method on the User controller.

Comment: DSO, maybe. My assumptions about the way routes works was correct. Routes set up first take precedence, confirmed by Brannon. But I'm getting this weird 404 error. Maybe other users will run into this at the same time that they have questions about Routing precedence.

Comment: JMs, its the default. And right now the View is the default also. code: public class UserController : Controller {  public ActionResult Index() { return View(); } }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your User controller should have

```
public class UserController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index(string domain, string username) { return View(); }
}
```

The two variables on the Index method of the user controller get picked up from the route.

Comment: Wait... nope that did it. I had a typo. Thanks JMs.

Answer (score 37):

`MapRoute()` is an extension method over `Routes.Add()`.  Use `MapRoute()`, unless you need to do something more complex than it allows.

Routes are evaluated in the order they are defined, so those you called first.

Comment: That's what I thought. And I'm having my first route entirely overlooked. see update on question

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question, which also matches the title (so it helps people searching SO for "MapRoute vs Add"). @BuddyJoe, please consider marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use!

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "User",                                                     
            "User/{domain}/{username}",                           
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username= UrlParameter.Optional }      
        );

       }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```