# What is the difference between Routes.Add and MapRoute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have only used MapRoute and slightly wondering where Routes.Add is used and on what scenario and how it differs from MapRoute?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513663/asp-net-mvc-maproute-versus-routes-add-and-404s. I can't mark as dupe though.

Comment: Yes thanks. I think it is the same question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MapRoute is just a wrapper around the more generalized Route.Add() It's an extension method to be exact.

Routing isn't specific to MVC, and therefore allows you to supply any suitable Route. This makes it extremely flexible and allows you to implement your own custom RouteHandlers. I did this back in ASP.Net 3.5 for .aspx pages.

It looks something like this:

```
routes.Add("Blah", 
   Route("custom/{stuff}", new SecretSauceRouteHandler()))
```